# nginx port 443 access denied

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ssl

I am trying to use ssl on nginx /django in ec2 .

This is the config

```
server {
        listen       443;
        ssl          on;
        ssl_certificate        /apps/cert-chain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key    /apps/private.key;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        server_name  mytest.com;

            location /static {
             alias /apps/static/;
            }

            location / {
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                 proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                 proxy_redirect off;
                 proxy_read_timeout 75s;
                 proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
                 if (!-f $request_filename) {
                     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9006;
                     break;
                 }
            }
    }
```

I get following error while starting nginx

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 443 is a restricted port (below 1024) and can only be bound to by an admin.

The best way to handle this is to bind to a different port (8443 or something similar) and then forward the traffic from 443 via something like iptables which runs as the system.